# cohomology of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne book (III.5.1) say that the natural map 
$$H^0(\mathbb{P}^r_{A},\mathcal{O}(n)) \times H^r(\mathbb{P}^r_{A},\mathcal{O}(-n-r-1)) \rightarrow H^r(\mathbb{P}^r_{A}, \mathcal{O}(-r-1))$$
 is a perfect pairing of finitely generated free $A$-modules for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

I heard that we can prove $H^d(\mathbb{P}^r_{A}, \mathcal{O}(n))=0$ for $n\geq -d$ using the above fact...
I try this proof... but I can't prove..

Comment: Have a look at Hartshorne's proof of III.5.1 (b).